# How do I solve access issues?

Tags: mysql, remote-access

When I log into the server with

```
[mysql -u rayzer5_root -p'***********' -h 173.231.211.221]
```

It connects but I cannot access my database.

When I try to log in with

```
[mysql -u rayzer5_root -p'***********' -h 173.231.211.221 -D rayzer5_orange_db
```

I get

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'rayzer5_root'@'c-98-249-0-68.hsd1.va.comcast.net' (using password: YES)

When I am signed in with `[mysql -u rayzer5_root -p'*********' -h 173.231.211.221]` I can use `SHOW GRANTS;` and I get

```
Grants for rayzer5_root@98.249.0.68
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'rayzer5_root'@'98.249.0.68' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*50A18D5B2BECC59BC9EEA4702519B53063772CBD'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `rayzer5\_orange\_db`.* TO 'rayzer5_root'@'98.249.0.68'
```

How do I get the server to see me as `rayzer5_root'@'98.249.0.68` rather than `Rayzer5_root'@'c-98-249-0-68.hsd1.va.comcast.net`?

Comment: Why don't you just grant access using the hostname instead of IP address?

Comment: What does `SELECT user();` show?

Comment: @Bamar I am a noob, but I have hosting on inmotion.com. I am trying to access from my laptop with command line. SELECT user(); returned:

rayzer5_root@c-98-249-0-68.hsd1.va.comcast.net

Thank you btw for your response.

Comment: When I try to grant privileges I get:

ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'rayzer5_root'@'c-98-249-0-68.hsd1.va.comcast.net' (using password: YES)

When I SHOW GRANTS; I get:

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'rayzer5_root'@'c-98-249-0-68.hsd1.va.comcast.net' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*50A18D5B2BECC59BC9EEA4702519B53063772CBD'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `rayzer5\_orange\_db`.* TO 'rayzer5_root'@'c-98-249-0-68.hsd1.va.comcast.net

Comment: Ok, it changes and I made no changes I just used SHOW GRANTS again and it returned:


GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'rayzer5_root'@'98.249.0.68' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*50A18D5B2BECC59BC9EEA4702519B53063772CBD'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `rayzer5\_orange\_db`.* TO 'rayzer5_root'@'98.249.0.68'

So I don;t understand why it is saying ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.se].